# setVisibility for menu action item

Tags: java, android

Can you help me?
I'm trying to create a menu where items appear at the touch of a button. I think I should make the menu items `visible:false`, and then switch this property in `MainActivity`. But I can't do it rightly. I need 3 new menu items.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    Button button;
    TextView textView4;
    EditText editText;
    private Object Menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        final Menu action_item4 = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.action_item4);


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Menu action_item4 = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.action_item4);
                 action_item4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          }
        });
    }
```

I see an error: Cannot resolve method `setVisibility(int)`

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way of creating a custom menu.
If you want to show a custom menu on click of a button then,

Create a file poupup_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="One"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Two"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>
```

In your button click

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

             //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);
        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater()
            .inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        popup.show(); //showing popup menu
    }
});
```

You can add more items to the menu as follows

```
popup.getMenu().add("title");
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting solution! But I have already implemented part of the menu (3 items) and when I click the button 1 time, I need the appearance of the 4th item, when I click the second time the 5th menu item, when I click the third time the 6th item.

Comment: @test_pilot in that case you can add menu items in consecutive clicks of the button

Comment: @test_pilot   I have updated my answer about how to add item dynamically in a menu

Comment: Thanks! but the menu should not be a pop up menu. All items should be in three points on the top right